# jQuery each: Use a variable in a key name

Tags: jquery, key, each

I have a function that retrieves some data via AJAX in JSON format, and I'm doing an `$.each` loop to process the data. What I'm doing right now is something like this:

```
$.each(result, function(i, field){
    window.localStorage[cumple1LAC] = field.cumple1LAC;
    window.localStorage[cumple2LAC] = field.cumple2LAC;
    window.localStorage[cumple3LAC] = field.cumple3LAC;
    window.localStorage[cumple4LAC] = field.cumple4LAC;
    window.localStorage[cumple5LAC] = field.cumple5LAC;
    ....
    ....
    ....
});
```

So most of the keys are identical except for the numeric id. When it comes to using the retrieved data, I'm doing something like this:

```
for (i=1;i<=numItems;i++){
    var cumple = window.localStorage['cumple'+i+'LAC'];
    $('input[name=cumple'+i+'LAC]').val([cumple]);
}
```

Since there are A LOT of items, I'd like to loop through the ids in the `$.each` loop, in a similar fashion to what I'm doing in the for loop, to avoid hundreds of lines of code (which I've already coded, but mainteinance-wise it's a pain in the ass). Is it possible to do? I wouldn't like to use numeric indexes to access the data in the retrieved array, I want to stick to key value pairs.

Comment: Have you tried:  `window.localStorage["cumple" + i + "LAC"] = field["cumple" + i + "LAC"];`?

Comment: If you're storing them like that why bother with the `cumpleXLAC` at all? Just store them in a single array by index

Comment: As you seem to access all the values all the time, convert your data to to a Json string and store a single localstorage value. Deserialise on read to get back your data.

Comment: @freedomn-m Gotta try that!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's a part of an internal app for my company, there's quite a lot of data so I can't really use only indexes, I need to keep the key:value pair structure. And it has to save the values in the localStorage for it to work offline, so an array is not an option. But thanks.

Comment: @GoneCoding I need to store the values independently so that I can manipulate each value without affecting the others, so I can't really store all of it in a single value. The app is working fine as is, but I'd like to improve the code a bit, to shorten it and make it easier to maintain.

Comment: Added option below. You can treat any object as a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat your `field` object as a dictionary and use the property names:

```
for (var key in field) {
  window.localStorage[key] = field[key];
}
```

**JSfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/rzth3hm5/